# Files greater than 1 GB not downloading completely on SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

When we click "send to" -> "download a copy" of a large file the download terminates after a few kb.  But it downloads correctly when you right click "Save target as...".

Anyone experience this issue or have suggestions on possible resolutions to this issue?  We haven't been able to find much on the internet about this nor get any useful error from the system.

Reproducing this issue on multiple browsers, multiple machines and multiple environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for downloading is the same as uploading! the question is, how long does it take for it to time out? have you tried smaller files?

the issue could be with http request where the setting in your web.config is set to a low number so when it reaches that number (seconds) it times out and you dont download!

also have you checked your log to see any errors being produced at:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

for increasing timeout:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Note We recommend that you set the maxAllowedContentLength value
>   slightly larger than the maximum file upload size that you have
>   configured in SharePoint. If the maxAllowedContentLength value is
>   equal to or smaller than maximum file upload size that is configured
>   in SharePoint, users will not receive the error message that they are
>   exceeding the size limit if they try to upload a file size larger than
>   that specified by the administrator.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083

i know the above is not for 2010 but its very similar if not the same!

if you want 2010:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/09/04/how-to-increase-the-timeout-for-a-sharepoint-2010-website.aspx

Comment: Uploading works without issue.  Downloading fails within seconds... only get 5kb or so of 1GB.  Says download complete.